# Ansible find module giving error "does not seem to be a valid directory or it cannot be accessed" absolute path

Tags: ansible, find

Ansible find module isn't working as expected.

So i have three instances 
One is test node , second controller node and third is from where i am running my ansible playbook

I am trying to generate ssh-keys on test_nodes and then fetching the public keys from those nodes. This is working fine.

Then I am trying to appending these public keys in the authorized_keys file of a different host(controller_node). For this, I am using the find module to get list of files and then loop over these files in authorized_key module.

I was using :

```
- name: Set authorized key file taken from file
            authorized_key:
                    user: absrivastava
                    key: "{{ lookup('file','item') }}"
                    state: present
            #with_file:  
                    - "/home/absrivastava/ANSIBLE/ssh-keys/*/home/ribbon/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"      This didnt work
            #with_filetree:
                    - "/home/absrivastava/ANSIBLE/ssh-keys/*/home/ribbon/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"      This was not appending data
```

But it didnt seem to work. So i am using find to get list of files and then iterate over them.

```
- name: Generate ssh keys
  hosts: media_nodes
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
          - name: key generation
            openssh_keypair:
                    path: ~/.ssh/id_ssh_rsa
                    force: True
            register: public_key
          - debug:
                  var: public_key.public_key
          - name: fetch public key from all nodes
            fetch:
                    src: ~/.ssh/id_ssh_rsa.pub
                    dest:  ssh-keys/

- name: Controller play
  hosts: controller
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
          - name: Find list of public key files
            find:
                    paths: /home/abhilasha/ANSIBLE/ssh-keys/
                    file_type: file
                    recurse: yes
                    patterns: ".*pub"
                    use_regex: yes
            register: files_matched

          - name: debug files matched
            debug:
                    var: files_matched.files

          - name: Debug files_matched loop
            debug:
                    var: item.path
            loop: "{{ files_matched.files|flatten(levels=1) }}"
            loop_control:
                    label: "{{ item.path }}"

          - name: Set authorized key file taken from file
            authorized_key:
                    key: "{{ lookup('file','item') }}"
                    state: present
            with_file:
                    - "{{ files_matched.files }}"


- name: Find list of public key files
This play is not working giving error

TASK [Find list of public keys] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_controller] => {"changed": false, "examined": 0, "files": [], "matched": 0, "msg": "/home/abhilasha/ANSIBLE/ssh-keys/ was skipped as it does not seem to be a valid directory or it cannot be accessed\n"}
```

Comment: Are you able to find using find command in linux?

Comment: yes

find ssh-keys/ -name "*pub"
ssh-keys/10.0.0.82/home/user/.ssh/id_ssh_rsa.pub
ssh-keys/test.pub

Comment: Are you using the same user via ansible and manual?

Comment: So these files are prsent on my vm-instance where i am running the ansible script , i want to copy the content of these files to the controller instance So these files are supposed to be present on the controller itself or on the vm-instance?

Comment: To answer your question i am running ansible script and the find command with the same user privileges

Comment: fetch module will copy the file to the ansible server.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so i got the issue , i was using hosts: controller for this play but the files are on my test VM instance .

But I am not sure how to still solve my problem. I want to use publoc keys on my local and then append it to controller server

```
- name: Fetch public key files from localhost
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  tasks:
          - name: Find list of public keys
            find:
                    paths: ssh-keys/
                    file_type: file
                    recurse: yes
                    patterns: "pub"
                    use_regex: yes
                    hidden: yes
            register: files_matched

          - name: Debug files_matched loop
            debug:
                    var: item.path
            loop: "{{ files_matched.files|flatten(levels=1) }}"
            loop_control:
                    label: "{{ item.path }}"

- name: Add Public keys to controller authorized keys
  hosts: controller
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

          - name: Set authorized key file taken from file
            authorized_key:
                    key: "{{ lookup('file','item') }}"
                    state: present
            with_file:
                    - "{{ files_matched.files }}"
```

I am unable to use files_matched variable outside the scope of that play. How can i make this work. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to copy/**find files from your local machine** to the remote, by default the `find` module will run on the remote, not your local machine. As a result, the error will be thrown if those directories don't exist on your remote.

So you just tell it to "find" on your local machine by specifying `delegate_to: localhost` and it should work.

```yaml
tasks:
  - find:
      paths:
        - local_dir1
        - local_dir2
      file_type: file
      patterns: '*.tgz'
    register: files_output
    # Execute task on this host instead of the target (inventory_hostname).
    delegate_to: localhost

  - block:
      - set_fact:
          files: "{{ files_output.files | map(attribute='path') }}"
      - set_fact:
          files: '{{ files + more }}'
        vars:
          more:
            - '{{playbook_dir}}/remote.sh'

  - debug:
      msg: '{{ item }}'
    loop: '{{ files }}'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"msg": "/home/abhilasha/ANSIBLE/ssh-keys/ was skipped as it does not seem to be a valid directory or it cannot be accessed\n"*

A: Take a look at the directory *ssh-keys/* at *controller* and check the content. Instead of

```
paths: /home/abhilasha/ANSIBLE/ssh-keys/
```

*find* it in the same path

```
path:  ssh-keys/
```

it has been *fetch* to

```
dest:  ssh-keys/
```

Comment: even if i use the path ssh-keys, still same error

TASK [Find list of public keys] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_controller] => {"changed": false, "examined": 0, "files": [], "matched": 0, "msg": "ssh-keys/ was skipped as it does not seem to be a valid directory or it cannot be accessed\n"}

Comment: Strange. You can't see the files with the public keys in the directory where the keys have been stored?

Comment: So the way the pub file is being stored is in this path : ssh-keys/10.0.0.82/home/user/.ssh/id_ssh_rsa.pub

But also i put one ssh-keys/test.pub file

But still i am not getting any files

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the paths as below and try

```
- name: fetch public key from all nodes
  fetch:
     src: ~/.ssh/id_ssh_rsa.pub
     dest:  /tmp/ssh-keys/
```

```
- name: Find list of public key files
  find:
     paths: /tmp/ssh-keys/
     file_type: file
     recurse: yes
     patterns: ".*pub"
     use_regex: yes
  register: files_matched
```

Comment: Stilll getting same error

    "msg": "/tmp/ssh-keys/ was skipped as it does not seem to be a valid directory or it cannot be accessed\n"